# Isn't There A Much Simpler Way To Explain Why Quantum Entaglement At Distance Isn't Utile - That Spins Already Exist & React To Detection Predictably?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

Tell me if this concept works for explaining in a much simpler way, why purposeful entanglement outcomes like FTL communication cannot work - and without relying on complex analyses of 'spooky action', 'hidden variables', Bell's theorem, etc.

Can't we just say that when two particles are entangled, that the entanglement 1) creates mirroring properties in each particle to the other, because of their orientation and influence on each other, 2) that when the two particles separate, they naturally retain those properties until interfered with (by, for example, a spin measurement), and 3) even if the same measurement performed separately on each particle changes the particles' properties, the properties are still mirrored, and so deliver predicable 'spinup/spindown' type results?

Here's a simple visual analogy for this lay explanation.

Let's picture two identical tops with geared edges, spinning together each with gears fully enmeshed in the other so that one is spinning clockwise and the other counterclockwise. The tops are held up in a magnetic field in a friction-less environment so that they do not tilt or fall and keep spinning indefinitely in the same plane. The tops are induced to separate and go spinning away from each other meeting no resistance (each still mirroring the other). The tops are spinning so quickly that it is not possible for a new observer to see which direction each is spinning. For each top, an observer 'measures' its spin by very precisely pegging an identical vertical rod in its path, in each case causing each top, on contact with its rod, to slow down and visibly spin off away from the rod, with the spin direction of each top now evident. It is a given when these measurements are taken, that one top will be spinning clockwise and the other counterclockwise. No spooky action, no hidden variables, no equations, just basic predictable mechanics.

So again the question. Isn't this both an easier way to explain the actual phenomenon taking place, and explain it in simple lay terms that don't require any in depth quantum explanations,  speculations or proofs?

thanks

Eric Brooks
SF, CA

Comment: "The tops are spinning so quickly that it is not possible for a new observer to see which direction each is spinning" this would be a hidden variable (the direction the top is spinning). The problem is that we can measure the rotation about different axes and, if, we, assume the tops were already spinning in some direction, there is no way to make those different possible measurements consistent without FTL communication between the tops. This is Bell's theorem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As this post has nothing to do with entanglement, you might want to delete that tag.

Comment: You might be interested in reading the classic article ["Is the Moon There When Nobody Looks?"](https://physics.csuchico.edu/kagan/435B/problems/Mermin.pdf) by David Mermin, which gives a nice exposition of why this sort of idea ("hidden variables") is in conflict with experiment.

Comment: As this question has apparently been 'closed' partly due to comments it allegedly does not involve entanglement, I must reply the question quite clearly involves entanglement, therefore closing it over entanglement is erroneous. As to the question being off topic in general this seems to have been determined simply because of subjective disagreement with the question adopting a theory that is well published and still taken seriously. Therefore the question was closed because of an administrator's personal disagreement with that theory. Is this site for exploration or for gatekeeping orthodoxy?

Comment: Brookse32, please be fair. This site is of very high quality one and therefore the tolerance for unorthodox questions is low. Reasonable questions (from your point of view or mine) about findings that are 50 or even 100 years old are sometimes tolerated, but never answered. Here are learned physicists on the way, whose curiosity is limited to their narrow research area (if den available).

Comment: A site which has a 'low tolerance for unorthodox questions' (especially when it comes to science, the very *nature* of which is to continuously re-question its assumptions) is the not a 'high quality' site, it is a low quality site. There is nothing incorrect or illegitimate about questioning Bell's resolutions of quantum physics and seeking better answers.

Comment: In response to your comment, I can't see any way in which this question relates to entanglement.  You give an example involving two tops that are clearly not entangled, and therefore has nothing to do with things that **are** entangled.     If you pose a question about why mice don't have trunks, that doesn't count as a question about elephants.

Comment: The question is specifically *about* explaining entangled particles to lay people, and furthermore how to explain to them how entanglement does *not* maintain at a distance (from an Einsteinian perspective). That is why the word "entanglement" is in the very title of the question. Those of you claiming that a question which quite obviously concerns entanglement, somehow doesn't, are simply saying that the question doesn't conform to *your* idea of how entanglement operates. Can we please think outside of the box? Especially when there is a cat in the box?

Comment: This is like explaining how cars work by describing a man who walks to work and saying "See?  No engines, no gasoline!".   You have pointed to something that is **not** entanglement and said "See?  no hidden variables, no spooky action, etc.".  How does the fact that none of these issues arise in the **absence** of entanglement convey any information at all about entanglement?

Comment: Entanglement is a real verified phenomenon. The question is, how do we interpret what we observe as entanglement, and especially, whether that observed entanglement maintains at long distances. So the analogy is actually this: Explaining to a man who is walking to work, that he cannot (as he wishes to) *drive* to work, because he does not own a car.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The whole confusion with polarised entanglement of particles comes from the fact that, firstly, you insist on the notion of spin and, secondly, the polarisation is generated randomly in the experiment. Let me explain this briefly.

Spin - in which nothing rotates - manifests itself when a particle moves through a magnetic field in which it is deflected. At the same time, the concept of spin always correlates with the magnetic field of the particle (its magnetic moment). If we leave the concept of spin completely aside for the moment, the following picture emerges.

1. the particle is deflected in the magnetic field due to the interaction of its magnetic dipole with the external field under the emission of EM radiation (the concept of spin is thereby invalid).
2. when polarised entangled particles are generated, their magnetic dipoles are entangled, up and down.
3. the up and down refers only to the fact that the particles are aligned antiparallel. Their common orientation in space is purely coincidental. Only such experimental results are accessible to us so far.
4. when the particles are detected, the polarisers, which are supposed to detect the particle orientation, are fixed in their rotational position, which leads to a random result in the detection. Only statistically can the correlation between the two particle orientations be detected, but a 100% result cannot be achieved. Our measuring device is therefore imperfect - naturally because of the random alignment when the particle entanglement is generated.

You are absolutely right when you interpret the results of the entanglement experiments as you describe above. However, science is based on consensus and so you get minus points here (and a plus from me).

Answer (score 0):

That would work, if you were only ever allowed to measure spins along a single axis. But, in fact, we can measure the spins along any axis we want, and it can be along a different axis for each "top." Before you have a complete theory, you have to pick a probability distribution for what result you get for each "top" if you measure it a specific angle.

As it turns out, it doesn't matter what probability distribution you pick for each individual top- no probability distribution can replicate the joint probability distribution predicted by quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn this into a post that's somehow related to entanglement, you should change your thought experiment to something like the following:

1. After the tops are separated, if you and I each measure our tops, we always find that they have opposite spins.
2. Except:  If either you or I scratches our nose while measuring, then we find that the tops have opposite spins only 99% of the time.
3. Except:  If we **both** scratch our noses while measuring then we find that the tops always have the **same** spin.

Note that you can maybe explain the second result by suggesting that a nose scratch causes you to mis-measure about 1% of the time.  But now how do you explain the third result?

These particular numbers (100%, 99%, and 0%) are not achievable in quantum mechanics, but numbers that are equally unrealizable in any classical model **are** achievable.  If you have a model that works for quantum mechanics, it should work for the above as well.  (I exaggerated the numbers to make the issue crystal clear, but exactly the same issue arises with the numbers that are both predicted by quantum mechanics and confirmed by experiment).

If you don't have a story that fits a scenario like this, then you are not talking about entanglement.